# window buttons, notifications have all turned blue

Tags: xubuntu, themes, notification

Using xubuntu 14.04.  Normally, I use greybird appearance theme (and bluebird for window manager).  I tried some others, but after going back to greybird, found that all the window buttons on the panels had turned dark blue.  Before, they had been black except for minimized or active windows.  Also noticed that the bars on system load monitor, sensor plugin, and network monitor have become dark blue, also the desktop notifications are all blue.  These all used to be black.  How to get it back to how it was before?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this on the xfce forums.  The thread is here: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=10406

There was a gtk override, and I had to rename a couple of files.